# Ubuntu Has Low Volume After Start-up

Tags: 13.10, sound, volume-control

After booting my computer running Ubuntu 13.10, the volume always starts at around 30%. This happens with the default volume program and pulse audio. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command in a terminal:
`sudo alsactl store 0`

Try also this one, a  recent pc may have 2 sound devices :

`sudo alsactl store 1`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I started getting a ton of errors and just decided to re-install the OS